# Vuex mapstate object undefined and "[vuex] unknown mutation type: "

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm new with vue.js and vuex and I've an issue with the mapstate object, first I've only one module in my store:

```
-Store
 -index.js
 -mutations.js
 -actions.js
 -state.js
```

**state.js :**

```
export default {
    userInfo: {
        messages: [{ 1: 'test', 2: 'test' }],
        notifications: [],
        tasks: []
    }
}
```

So when I try to access the userInfo object everything works correctly:

```
computed: {
    ...mapState(["userInfo"]),
}
```

Then I decided to create modules:

```
-Store
 -modules
  -ldap.js
 -commons.js
 -index.js
```

So the `userInfo` is in the `commons.js` file and now when I try to get the object I always get `undefined`:

**commons.js**

```
// state
const state = {
    userInfo: {
        messages: [{ 1: 'test', 2: 'test' }],
        notifications: [],
        tasks: []
    }
}

export default {
    actions,
    mutations,
    state  
}
```

**Component.vue**

```
computed: {
    ...mapState(["userInfo"]), // <---- undefined
}
```

**main.js :**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import commons from './commons'
import ldap from './modules/ldap'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules : {
        commons,
        ldap
    } 
})
```

Can you tell me how to access the userInfo object?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you setup your module? Actually I don't see any evidence that you're using vuex-modules?

Comment: Did you namespace your module....i.e set`namespaced: true`  in your module?

Comment: No I dont, I will try to set the namespaced, thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Considering:

- Your **commons.js** is as follows:

  ```js
  // state
  const state = {
      userInfo: {
          messages: [{ 1: 'test', 2: 'test' }],
          notifications: [],
          tasks: []
      }
  }

  export default {
      namespaced: true, // <== make sure this is defined
      actions,
      mutations,
      state  
  }
  ```
- And **main.js** imports it like:

  ```js
  import commons from './commons'
  // ..
  export default new Vuex.Store({
      modules : {
          commons,
          ldap
      } 
  })
  ```
- Then *update* on **Component.vue**:

  ```js
  import { mapState } from 'vuex'

  // ...

  computed: {
      ...mapState('commons', ["userInfo"]), // <== add module name here
  }
  ```

  Or

  ```js
  import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'

  const { mapState, mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers('commons')

  // ...                          notice module name above ^^^^^^^^^

  computed: {
      ...mapState(["userInfo"]),
  }
  ```

> "[vuex] unknown mutation type: "

Since you are now namespacing your `commons` module, that modules' **mutations now must be prefixed**.

So, say you had a mutation like:

```
const mutations = {
    changeName(state, data) {
        state.name = data;
    }
}
export default {
    namespaced: true, 
    actions,
    mutations,
    state  
}
```

And you used it like:

```
this.$store.commit('changeName', "New Name");
```

Now use it like:

```
this.$store.commit('commons/changeName', "New Name");
```

Comment: Yes I did that but do you know why my mutations stop working??
"[vuex] unknown mutation type: "

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define each module as a individual store, here some pseudo example.

```
// authStore.js

import mutations from './authMutations'
import actions from './authActions'
import getters from './authGetters'

const initialState = {
  ...
}

export default {
  state: initialState,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

Then, register the modules

```
import authStore from './authStore'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
   {...authStore, namespaced: true},
   {...postStore, namespaced: true} // some other module defined like auth
  }
})

new Vue({
  ....
  store: store
})
```

And then, on the component use it:

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'

// map state and actions of the module
const { mapState, mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers('auth')

export default {
  computed: {
     ...mapState({
       prop1: 'prop1'
     })
  }
}
```

[Vuex modules docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have namspaced your modules by adding `namespaced: true` in your module.

So you should pass the module name  as the first argument to the `mapState` helpers so that all bindings are done using that module as the context. See [Binding Helpers with Namespace](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace)

```
computed: { 
    ...mapState('commons' , ["userInfo"])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is *really* unclear in the documentation but namespaced: true is *required* to use the map functions.

At least as of the last comment in this discussion
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/855

Answer (score 0):

Without the need to namespace your modules you can use the callback variant of mapstate:

```
computed: {
    ...mapState({
        userInfo: state => state.commons.userInfo,
    }),
},
```